# Komma vor einem einzelnen Gedankenstrich

Tags: sentence-structure, spelling, punctuation, comma

[*Der Zauberberg*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Zauberberg) wimmelt von Sätzen, die einen Gedankenstrich (Halbgeviertstrich) enthalten, dem ein Komma vorangeht: `[…], – […].`

Beispiele:

> - Der gute Joachim hatte einige Blumen in eine kleine Vase auf die Kommode gestellt, – was eben im zweiten Grase zu finden gewesen war, etwas Schafgarbe und ein paar Glockenblumen, von ihm selbst am Hange gepflückt.
> - »Epochal für die Entwicklung unserer Schiffahrt, – gar nicht zu überschätzen.«
> - Joachim Ziemßen nämlich war krank, – nicht krank wie Hans Castorp, sondern auf wirklich mißliche Weise krank, es war sogar ein großer Schrecken gewesen.
> - Ein Frostschauer überlief ihn, – einer und dann mehrere rasch hintereinander.

<sub>Quelle: Thomas Mann, *Der Zauberberg* (ISBN 978-3-596-29433-6): S. 21; 26; 55; 125.</sub>

Was hat es damit auf sich? Ist das Komma da nicht überflüssig? Ist diese Verwendung überhaupt erlaubt/richtig? Falls nicht, war sie es 1913–1924?

Comment: Spontan denke ich, es macht nur Sinn, wenn es eine abrupte Auslassung darstellen würde. So was wie "Ach du heilige –, das ist nicht nicht wahr"

Comment: Thomas Mann darf machen was er will. Für mich liest sich die Komma-Gedankenstrichkombination etwas anders als nur der Gedankenstrich - eine größere Pause. Ich sehe dies wie die Wortwahl bei Gedichten: künstlerische Freiheit.

Comment: Nehmen wir an es wäre nicht erlaubt, was dann? Stampfen wir dann alle Ausgaben des Zauberbergs ein?

Comment: @Ingo: Was dann ist? Dann weiß ich zwei Dinge: 1) ich sollte dieses Konstrukt nicht verwenden; 2) ich sollte es als Fehler anstreichen. ·· Wer mag, kann dann auch mutmaßen, dass Mann und seine Lektoren bestimmt wussten, dass dieses Konstrukt nicht regelkonform ist, und sich fragen, aus welchem Grund sie es trotzdem verwendet haben. ·· Ob man neue Editionen von schöngeistiger Literatur an aktuelle Rechtschreibregeln anpassen und alte Editionen gar einstampfen sollte, sind Fragen, die hier off-topic sind, denke ich.

Comment: @Ursula: Außerdem kann dies nur zutreffen, wenn der Autor sowohl Komma-Gedankenstrich-Kombinationen als auch einfache Gedankenstriche nutzt. Ansonsten ist die künstlerische Freiheit kaum von einer Marotte unterscheidbar. (Ich habe keine Ahnung, wie die jeweiligen Häufigkeiten im *Zauberberg* sind.) Wir hatten z. B. neulich schon mal eine Diskussion über J. K. Rowlings Angewohnheit, alle Erzählwelt-spezifischen Begriffe großzuschreiben, inkl. Adjektive und Verben.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Auch wenn es nicht explizit in den aktuellen Regeln steht, gibt es doch eine ganze Menge Regeln, aus denen implizit folgt, dass diese Gedankenstrich-Komma-Kombinationen falsch sind:

- Wannimmer eine Regel besagt, dass in einem Fall wie in Deinen Beispielen ein Komma bzw. Gedankenstrich gesetzt werden kann, wird erwähnt, dass auch das jeweils andere Satzzeichen möglich ist (siehe z. B. die Einführung zur »Gliederung innerhalb von Ganzsätzen«, § 77, § 84)
- Komma und Gedankenstrich kennzeichnen hier dasselbe. Und wenn etwas bereits gekennzeichnet ist, braucht die nicht erneut zu geschehen.
- Es gibt kein einziges derartiges Beispiel.

Beachte, dass ein Komma hinter oder vor einem mit Gedankenstrichen gekennzeichneten Einschub stehen muss, wenn es der Hauptsatz bei Weglassung des Einschubs erfordern würde – Deine Beispiele sind aber keine Einschübe.

---

Mein Duden von 1925 verliert nicht viele Worte zum Gedankenstrich:

> 1. Der Gedankenstrich steht innerhalb eines Satzes zur Bezeichnung einer längern [sic] Pause, besonders um auf etwas Unerwartetes vorzubereiten, z. B. *Er will der Väter Thron besteigen und – wandelt auf ein Blutgerüst. »Der Schatz liegt« – hier starb der Vater.*
> 2. Der Gedankenstrich steht vor und nach solchen selbständigen eingeschobenen Sätzen die den **Nachdruck des Gesagten zu erhöhen** bestimmt sind, z. B. *Denn Bank an Bank gedränget sitzen – es brechen fast der Bühne Stützen –, herbeigeströmt von fern und nah, der Griechen Völker wartend da.*

Ich denke, die Beispiele der ersten Regel kann man durchaus als parallel zu Deinen betrachten. Betrachtet man dies als Vorgabe, sollten keine Kommata gesetzt werden.

Nebenbei wurde im Fraktursatz (in dem wohl auch die Erstauflage des *Zauberbergs* erschien) noch ein echter Geviertstrich¹ als Gedankenstrich verwendet. Die Lücke, die der Gedankenstrich in den Text riss, war also deutlich größer als heute und ein zusätzliches Komma war um so weniger nötig.

¹ Heutige Geviertstriche sind in der Regel deutlich kürzer als ein Geviert.